# How to pass variable from controller to UserMailer

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want the url will be available in Email\html\forgot_password_email.ctp

method in controller

```
public function forgotPassword(){
$url = Router::url(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset'], true) . '/' . $passkey;
 $this->getMailer('User')->send('forgotPassword', [$user]);
}
```

UserMailer.php

```
->to($user->email)
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->subject(sprintf('Forgot Password link  %s', $user->username))
    ->viewVars([
    'username'=> $user->username,
    'useremail'=>$user->email,
    'userid' => $user->id
    ])
   ->template('forgotPasswordEmail')
```

I can print this 3 variables such as username,useremail,userid in Email\html\forgot_password_email.ctp   but I dont know how to print the url

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you copy and pasted but didn't read or understood what is explained [on this page](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails) in the manual.

The 2nd arg of send() is an array that takes the args that are passed to your mailer function. So just pass the URL there. Or even better, because this doesn't belongs into the controller (remember: fat model, skinny controller): Generate the URL in the template and pass the token.

Comment: thats what i did in my activation upon register I just generate the url inside Email\html\registered.ctp      but now i cant echo the token even i set in viewvars like  'passkey' => $user->pass_key    and <?php $resetUrl = Router::url(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset/' . $passkey ]);?>  the passkey code will not echo only the link  http://localhost/blog/users/reset/

Comment: You are not passing the key / URL to the mailer, nor are you passing them to the view vars. And your $passkey should be part of the URL array. Might work the way you do it but that's not how it should be done here. Maybe it's empty as well, you need to debug it if it's not there.

Comment: I  can now echo the passkey but, it does not  have the same value always, after i request forgot password the previous pass_key is passing the pass_key which is updated if user click forgot password  http://localhost/blog/users/reset/fe4203d1-190d-4e80-8891-6f406f29f9f6    this token is the previous data. and current token is not the same anymore? how this happen

Comment: I have a condition before sendmail    if ($this->Users->updateAll(['pass_key' => $passkey, 'timeout' => $timeout], ['id' => $user->id]))